# Is there a good reason why I shouldn't be mixing POST and GET parameters in a CGI query?

Tags: perl, post, cgi, get

Is there a good reason why I shouldn't be mixing POST and GET?

For example:

```
<form action="http://example.com/?param1=foo&param2=bar" method="post">
```

Comment: Perl's CGI seem to support them with the `url_param()` method.

Comment: As you pointed out `CGI.pm` supports such use. Being a drop in replacement for `CGI.pm`, `CGI::Simple` does so as well. If you are interested in any other library, you can read its documentation to find out or specify it by name so we can read its manual for you.

It is easier to evaluate whether your reasons for mixing query string parameters with post parameters are valid than to list all the reasons it might be a bad idea to do so.

Comment: Sinan - a somewhat valid example of such usage is having the action value passed as a parameter (via POST, or from DB or form config) - it's easier to use it as-is than parse it internally and then create hidden input elements for each item in the GET query that was passed.

Comment: @DVK I agree and I sometimes do use query string parameters that way although my personal preference is to use `path_info`. However, I can imagine (and have had to deal with) quite a few inappropriate uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As noted by comments to your question, [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) is OK
- [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Simple) is OK
- [EmbPerl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Embperl)'s `%fdat` is OK
- Everything else, you need to read documentation or just test.

The important question is why do you care about "most CGI libraries"? You should pick the library you are going to use and ask that question about that library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason to do this, at least with CGI.pm:

It's important to use the url (whether cgi parameters or path info) to provide some context for things like file uploads, where the $POST_MAX may be exceeded and all the post data be thrown away.  Only if the server knows what the attempted post was can it give a good error message.  (You could use HTTP_REFERER to guess, but I hate to ever depend on that.)